# Flutter->Getting Bio-metric FingerPrint Data/Image from device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

**Flutter**
**Dart**
**Mobile Application Development**
I am looking for a way to get fingerprint image from the sensor from mobile and send it to the server using dart. I am stuck on authenticating internally and can't seem to find any way to get the biometric fingerprint data from the device. Read many documentations regarding trusted parties and other stuff but am unable to get this specific description that could remotely satisfy the above mentioned requirement. Looking forward to hearing from you guys.

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65391611/14231239 ?

Comment: At least on Android, that is not possible, at least using on-device fingerprint sensors.

Comment: There are many applications that do these stuff. take fingerprint from your device and send it the server. examples are banking apps and other apps in the market. What alternatives do you suggest.. Do help me out,

Comment: Can you also share an sample code to the referred stack overflow solution.. i am desperate for this quest. Do help me. Regards..

Comment: "Can you also share an sample code to the referred stack overflow solution" - no, as there is NO code available because you do not have any access to the fingerprint/biometric data. There is just a way to check that the actual fingerprint presented is the one previously stored on the DEVICE (in the end, it is a TRUE/FALSE result from device's environment).

Comment: Thank you Michael Fehr. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Getting biometric auth from the device can be done by using plugins like [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth). No need to fetch the fingerprint image directly. The plugin returns a `boolean` if the user successfully used fingerprint auth on their device or not.

Comment: Is it possible to get user finger image? like if somehow you want to store it on your app